# Will in-app billing be available through the NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk, google-play, billing

I'm looking in to creating a game through the NDK using a `NativeApplication` for Gingerbread. I also want to be able to use the new in-app billing API Google is providing to developers though. I know it's not a finalized API just yet but I haven't seen an example of interacting with it through the NDK.

Does anyone have an idea of how it could be possible to use the in-app billing through the NDK or should I look into launching another Activity that uses the Java API?

Comment: Most likely your in app payment will have some UI, right? Are you going to develop that UI via the NDK, too?

Comment: I was hoping that I could use the same type of UI as my game using OpenGL ES but I guess launching another activity for DLC could also be an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The in-app billing API is a Binder interface. When you make a purchase request, the Market application takes over and displays a (partially transparent) activity on top of yours, which renders the purchase dialog.

If you want to access this through the NDK, my advice would be to make a bridge to the sample code we provide using JNI. I don't believe you have access to the Binder from the NDK.

Comment: That could definitely work too, I didn't even think of making a bridge. Thanks! :D